# How to call an AutoIt script in Python

Tags: python, selenium, call, autoit

How can I call an AutoIt EXE file to Python code?

I need add to code which were generated by a [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) AutoIt script.

Comment: You mean execute autoit.exe in python?
    `import os`    
    `os.system(".\autoit.exe")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to just run the AutoIt script then use `os.system` or `os.popen` and take a look at the page *[Running Scripts](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/running.htm)*. If you want to call AutoIt methods from your Python script then:

1. Register AutoItX3.dll in your system: `regsvr32 AutoItX3.dll`
2. Install [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)
3. Use AutoIt from your code as follows:

   ```
   import win32com.client

   autoit = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")

   autoit.AnyAutoitMethod()
   ```

Comment: Can we call a custom method over here? Say I have a method in myautoitFile.au3. Is there a way to call it?